# How to Bypass or Automate MacOS Software Check from Python

Tags: macos, python, gatekeeper

I have a python script running on MacOS that uses Selenium chromedriver. I use chromedriver_autoinstaller to check for and install the latest chromedriver automatically. The problem is, on MacOS, every new chromedriver has to be manually approved as a safe file downloaded from the internet and authorized with admin username and password for it to be able to run. I want this process to be either automatic or to bypass the security check and authorization for (preferably) chromedriver only. I don't want to ever have to authorize or press "Open" on the dialogue window that pops up each time a new version of chromedriver is downloaded. What are the best and safest ways to do this?

I have to authorize the dialogue boxes manually, and I want to automate or bypass this process.

Giving the approval command in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362018/macos-catalinav-10-15-3-error-chromedriver-cannot-be-opened-because-the-de requires administrator authentication and then the first time chromedriver runs it requires you to click open in a dialogue box. I am not sure how to automate the administrator authentication and how to click "Open" on the dialogue box in Python. Is there an easy solution to this problem or other workarounds?

Comment: Are you willing to become a developer so you could notarize the packages or use an MDM to push profiles and automate some of this? Short answer is don’t update for now

Comment: Can you not just delete the quarantine flag?

Comment: Yes, but doing that requires a admin authentication via a dialogue box once the command is given. After that, the first time chromedriver runs, yet another dialogue box requiring you to click "open" pops up. How do you automate that in Python?

Comment: sounds like you want spctl